# Where in the HAproxy C code repo is the part responsible of handling the failure of a server and falling back to a backup one?

Tags: c, haproxy

I'm trying to understand why instead of the fallback mechanism of haproxy working (in case of sticky connections) I'm getting 504 gateway timeout errors when a server fails although there are other backup servers available to handle the requests. So, I'm currently studying the C code of haproxy and would appreciate any pointers.

I tried increasing the "timeout server" config value in the haproxy configuration file from 3000ms to 30000ms and that eliminated the 504 errors but that solution wasn't accepted by the team leader because he said we cannot afford such a long timeout period.

Comment: There's a community forum at https://discourse.haproxy.org/ this may be a better place to ask

Comment: Which version are you running? have you seen this post: https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/intermittent-504-errors-and-sr-after-upgrade-to-1-7-10/2029 ? v1.7.11 fixes a 504/timeout-related bug IIUC.

Comment: @MortenJensen I'm running version 2.5.0 and I had a look at the post you provided. It mentions that the problem has been solved starting from version 1.8.